# Surjectivity of spectral measure associated to an isolated point

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $T$ be a normal bounded operator on a complex Hilbert space $H$. Suppose $\lambda$ is an isolated point in the spectrum of $T$. Then we can use functional calculus applied to the characteristic function $\mathbb{1}_{\{\lambda\}}$ to form the spectral projection $\mathbb{1}_{\{\lambda\}}(T)$. Since

$$(z-\lambda)\cdot\mathbb{1}_{\{\lambda\}}=0$$
as functions on the spectrum of $T$, it follows that for any $v\in H$,

$$(T-\lambda)\circ\mathbb{1}_{\{\lambda\}}(T)(v)=0,$$

so that the range of $\mathbb{1}_{\{\lambda\}}(T)$ lies within the $\lambda$-eigenspace of $T$.

**Question:** Is there a similarly simple argument that shows that $\mathbb{1}_{\{\lambda\}}(T)$ surjects onto the $\lambda$-eigenspace of $T$?

*Remark:* I am aware of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1229180/spectral-projection-and-isolated-point-of-spectrum) and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146435/why-call-this-a-spectral-projection), but am looking for an alternative approach that does not involve spectral measures or Borel functional calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If $Tx=\lambda x$, then $p(T)x=p(\lambda)x$ for any polynomial $p$. Taking norm limits, $f(T)x=f(\lambda)x$ for all continuous $f\in C(\sigma(T))$. As $\lambda$ is isolated, the function $1_{\{\lambda\}}$ is continuous on $\sigma(T)$. Thus $1_{\{\lambda\}}(T)x=x$.